# How to get JMeter Include Controller to use top-test plan's config elements?

Tags: httprequest, jmeter

In JMeter I am attempting to create a login test plan that can be used by many other test plans.  The setup is as follows:

**LoginTest.jmx**

```
     TestPlan
          TestFragement
               PostLogin_HTTPRequest
```

**OtherTest.jmx**

```
     TestPlan
          Thread Group
               HTTPRequestDefault (Contains web server name and port, HTTP request implementation and protocol)
               HTTPCookieManager
               OnceOnlyController
                    IncludeController (Includes test plan LoginTest.jmx)
               RuntimeController
                    HTTPRequest (reverts to login page because cookie is not stored)
                    ...
```

The issue is that for some reason the cookie manager and request defaults are not accessed by the included login test plan so the rest of the test does not work properly because the session cookie does not exist.

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong or can assist me in resolving this issue?  I am using JMeter Version 2.5 r1158837.

Answer (score 0):

As per reference [18.2.14 Include Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Include_Controller):

> If the test uses a Cookie Manager or User Defined Variables, **these
>   should be placed in the top-level test plan, not the included file**,
>   otherwise they are not guaranteed to work.